# PyQt Button clicked as soon as program ran

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Using Qt Designer, I have created a simple Dialogue box. I have added a submit button called `self.pushButton`. I keep having a problem that when I run the program, the button is automatically clicked. I am getting the program to print to the shell, "button clicked" and this appears as soon as the program is run.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(880, 479)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 351, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Rockwell Nova Light"))
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 741, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Rockwell Nova Light"))
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 100, 741, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Rockwell Nova Light"))
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 260, 161, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Rockwell Nova Light"))
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(714, 412, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Rockwell Nova Light"))
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 160, 741, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Rockwell Nova Light"))
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.home()
        self.click()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Welcome to PURA!", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "This app is your revision partner, helping you learn throughout the day.", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "To begin, first add a question below", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Multiple Choice", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "True or False", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Written Question", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Submit", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select the type of question you would like to make", None))

    def home(self):

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)

    def click(self):
        print("button clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It looks like you are modifying a QtDesigner generated file here. You might want to write a wrapper for this file and not directly write into it. If you ever change your UI and want to export it again, your manual changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a call to your click function at "setupUi"(line 75) function which is called to setup your ui at the beginning. So remove the `self.click()` from there.